# How do I use content containing razor markup as a parameter for a method?

Tags: razor

What I am trying to do is to be able to write javascript blended with razor styled markup and methods inside .cshtml file and send this to a separate method for usage later on.

My .cshtml looks something like this:

```
@{SomeClass.SaveForLater(@<script type="text/javascript">window.alert('@Model.SomeParamter')}</script>);
```

And inside the class SomeClass:

```
public static void SaveForLater(HtmlString str) {
    // will be using str.ToString() here and save the string output for use later on.
}
```

But what I receive is this error message:
CS1660: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Web.HtmlString' because it is not a delegate type

Am I using the wrong type for the argument or do I need to rethink the whole concept?

**Solution**
Thanks to SLaks below I ended up doing this:

```
public static void SaveForLater<T>(Func<T, HelperResult> template, dynamic model)
{
    // template(model).ToHtmlString()
}
```

Using it like this:

```
 @{SomeClass.SaveForLater<SomeModel>(
        @<script type="text/javascript">window.alert('@Model.SomeParamter')</script>,
        Model
        );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to take an [inline helper](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/04/dissecting-razor-part-9-inline-helpers.html).
You need to accept a `Func<Something, HelperResult>`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction, but if looking at my example, what would represent the "Something" class?

Comment: @MattiasHögnäs: Anything you want.  It will be passed to the action; see my blog post.  If you don't want to pass anything,. just use `object`.